# I want to attach multiple email addresses to a single inbox and then filter the emails that are received into folders

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange-2010, rules

As the title says, I want to create one inbox in Exchange 2010 and then attach a bunch (7-9) email addresses to it. Then I want to automatically filter the messages by recipient address and move them to folders.

Whats the best way to go about this? Creating a simple rule that does the above does not work as it becomes a client-only rule.

Why I want to do this is because instead of having a single internal mail address for repairs, the production people want to assign certain productgroups to certain people, but with the ability that everyone is still able to see/manage the other productgroups.

I figured making 9 AD accounts, with 9 inboxes and attaching 9 shared inboxes to all 9 workers is the more convoluted way, but I could be wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using Distribution Groups in Exchange.

Create 1 mailbox as you required.

Create 9 distribution groups each with their own email address and add the primary account as a member of the distribution group. (You can also add other users if they need to be aware of mails being received).

Using server side Roles you can then create rules that move message sent to a specified email address to a folder.